# WPF Commands in Control templates -> "CommandConverter cannot convert from > System.String."

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have a custom control template from Telerik and Ive added a (split)button to it. 
How to I bind a command handler to it? I have tried to add a public static command in a public class 
to use bindings like x:static ns:Class.Command and all sorts of variation (like below) and most of the SO-hits.

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadSplitButton}}, Path=ShowSearchCommand}" Margin="2" />
```

and

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{x:Static vm:MainWindowViewModel.ShowSearchCommand}" CommandParameter="one"/>
```

They all ends up in the error message

> NotSupportedException: CommandConverter cannot convert from
>   System.String.

Ive tried defining the commands (see below) in the viewmodel and in a class pf its own (Im using Prism (therefore the Delegate commands, but its doesnt have to be Delegate commands, as long as it works)

```
  //public static RoutedUICommand ShowSearchCommand = new RoutedUICommand("ShowSearchCommand", "ShowSearchCommand", typeof(TabbedWindowCommands));


//public static DelegateCommand ShowSearchCommand = new DelegateCommand();
```

Comment: Where is the command defined and how?

Comment: I updated the question, my comment got to messy

Comment: You still doesn't answer my question. Did you see my answer? The command shouldn't be static...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ShowSearchCommand` is not a property of the `RadSplitButton` itself but of its `DataContext`, you should include `DataContext` in the binding path:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadSplitButton}}, Path=DataContext.ShowSearchCommand}" Margin="2" />
```

You might also want to change the `AncestorType` to `Window` depending on where and how you set the `DataContext`.

Also note that you can only bind to public properties which means that `ShowSearchCommand` must be a property and not a field:

```
public DelegateCommand ShowSearchCommand { get; }
```